# Find a center of mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, mass

This is a problem I can’t seem to figure out.

Three wooden sticks, 20cm in lenght and 0,5N heavy. We stick them together, like the axis of a coordinate system (they stick together at one side, it’s like one quadrant of x,y,z coordinate system). Where is the center of mass?

My biggest problem with this is, that I don’t understand the formula completely.

$$\frac {\sum{r_i m_i}}{M}$$
I know that $r$ is a vector, but I still somehow always get it wrong. Aditional question is, where is it smart to measure the vector $r$ from?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation. Maybe you could explain a bit more *what* you don't understand about the formula given, and *how* you get it wrong when you try to apply it?

Comment: I thinkn I have, I don’t completly understand, where you should measure $r$ from, and if it’s important if you sum only $x$ or $y$ values or do you have to sum the whole vector.

Comment: On the last question, step 1 is always choosing a coordinate system to measure distances from, and making sure you are consistent in that choice. In this case it would make sense to use the common point of the three sticks as that simplifies things somewhat.

Answer (score 3):

The formula $$\vec r_{CM}= \sum_i \frac{\vec r_i m_i}{M}$$
can be seen like a weighted sum of the positions. It assumes you have a number of point masses located at $\vec r_i$. Let's start with two point masses to build intuition. The formula then becomes $\vec r_{CM}=\frac{m_1} M \vec r_1+\frac{m_2}M\vec r_2$. Here's a picture describing this situation:

[image: center of mass for 2 particles]

When the two masses are equal the center of mass lies in the center. When one of the masses is larger (depicted with a bigger circle here) the center of mass moves towards the biggest mass. The center of mass calculates an 'average of position' but gives bigger masses a bigger weight. To see this more clearly consider the case of $N$ particles with identical masses. You can calculate the $x$ and $y$-components as follows.
$$x_{CM}=\frac 1 N\sum_i x_i\\
y_{CM}=\frac 1 N\sum_i y_i
$$
Now you see each component is just the average.

To calculate your specific problem you can split the problem into parts: first calculate the centers of mass of each rod and then calculate the center of mass of these three. Let's pick a coordinate system that is aligned with the rods to make this easy. We can see by symmetry that the center of mass of a rod is in the middle, so the centers of mass are given by
$$r_1=(10,0,0)\\r_2=(0,10,0)\\r_3=(0,0,10)$$
for each of the rods. Can you now calculate the total center of mass?

Comment: Yes i did manage to solve it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The equation for the centre of mass in the vector form is written as this:

$$\mathbf r_{\text {COM}} = \frac {\sum{\mathbf r_i m_i}}{M}$$

which is equivalent to three equations

$$x_{\text {COM}} = \frac {\sum{x_i m_i}}{M}$$

$$y_{\text {COM}} = \frac {\sum{y_i m_i}}{M}$$

$$z_{\text {COM}} = \frac {\sum{z_i m_i}}{M}$$

And for the case where to measure the $r$ from then a true answer would be from anywhere but it is much useful to find it relative to body (like about some symmetric point).

---

**Hint for the question**: First find the position vector of the Centre of Mass (COM) of each rod. And then find the centre of mass the three COM that you get. You may notice while solving this question that the centre of masses are coplanar and therefore there COM lies in the plane that passes through them, you can see this in the following diagram:

[image: Centre of Mass]